# Fender telecaster - gap between neck pickup and pickguard

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

Just today I finally made my dream come true and bought my first Telecaster. I brought it home and it plays like a dream!

After I got to play with it for sometime and upon closer inspection, I noticed that there is a gap between the neck pickup and the pickguard. That gap, in fact, is big enough to fit a pick inside, as you can see in this photo:

[image: Fender telecaster pickup gap]

So since I’m not that knowledgeable about guitars, I’m wondering, would this be an issue? I’m just wondering whether dust or other debris can find its way in there...

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Check out this related question - https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/49375/importance-of-the-neck-joint-on-an-electric-guitar. Some of the answers may be useful

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I learnt quite a few things in it!

Comment: Just checked my '70s MiJ Fender Tele - couldn't push a pick in there! Maybe the tolerances aren't so tight these days!

Comment: Well, probably the guitars made in Japan are higher quality than those from Mexico too. But thanks for the information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's nothing to worry about, it will not cause any issues at all.

The important things in a guitar are others: wood resonance, good construction, straight neck, quality pickups and machine heads, well shaped nut, well aligned strings, good string action.